# Is this switch circuit correct?

Tags: transistors, current

This is a follow-up question to [How high is "high impedance" on this chip (CD74HC125E)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70574/how-high-is-high-impedance-on-this-chip-cd74hc125e)

I finally decided to use a pn2222 transistor to act as a switch that activates the transmitter. The circuit is as follow:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJejR1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In order to activate the transmitter TX, T1 and T2 must be (dis)connected. The goal of this circuit is to activate TX through the transistor Q1, depending on whether SW1 is open or closed.

Web URL for the transmitter (available in French an Dutch only): http://www.chacon.be/index.php/domotique/my-fox-domotique-a-distance/kit-va-et-vient-micro-modules-rec-em.html

Currently, the switch is actually a custom RJ45 plug, but will eventually be replaced by an arduino output. Feel free to ignore this part if not relevant.

I have three questions about this:

1. Does it look correct to you?
2. I calculated the voltage at the base of Q1 to be 1.1v, due to the voltage divider. Is this correct / does Q1 change something in this ? Is it enough/relevant? Provided that the goal is to make TX think that T1 and T2 are shorted.
3. I could not reduce the average current consumption of the whole circuit, even with more resistors. How can I reduce it?

Comment: Are you really sure that T1 and T2 are meant to be connected to each other to disable the transmitter? That just doesn't sound right. What about the common mode voltage of T1 and T2? Are these perhaps separate gate inputs so that one of them can be tied high or low and the other switched? We need to see the datasheet.  Your circuit is unlikely to be a good answer.

Comment: There's no datasheet. TX is a remote for a remote-controlled plug, available at a store. It can be linked to simple wall switches. So connect T1 and T2 to switch on, disconnect to switch off, that's it.

Comment: @Antoine_935 atleast can you give a link to the product which you are using or similar

Comment: Without better info on TX, this is no question at all.  Even a diagram of how this thing is normally used would help.  The hand waving just isn't making sense.

Comment: Come on, how can it be so hard to believe someone? Anyway, I added the link to the manufacturer's website. Available in French and Dutch only, and no trace of the manual (that's basically why I didn't put it in the first time)

Comment: @Antoine_935 i ask so many questions before i answer. most of the time, i dont give room for assumptions.there would be some design considerations like 1)why cannt you control the power of the transmitter instead of T1 and T2 (this doubt arises because of the quiescent current drawn by the TX if the device is to be operated by the battery you have to consider if wall powered no problem). 2)cost of the solution (there may be so many solutions available for your problem).if my comments are bothering you much sorry for that.

Comment: I do appreciate these concerns, I have to recognise that the strong reactions I met upset me. To answer you remarks: 1) the transmitter can, and will, be powered down, but this doesn't switch off the plug if it's on. 2) there's for sure a cheaper solution, but it probably involves manipulating the mains. Since I'm a newbie in this field, I try to stay as far as possible from the mains, hence my choice for a remote-controlled plug

Comment: User manual: http://www.chacon.be/media/sync/54737/From%20Chacon/54737%20User%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I checked the manual of the product you refer to (there IS a manual, however brief). I think I understand what you want and why.

The thingy is a transmitter that is intended to be connected to a normal (mains) switch, and to be paired with a receiver that mimics the switch state at another location.

You want to duplicate the effect of the normal switch with an arduino output, so you can use the arduino to remotely control some mains powered device.

Without knowing what is behind the two pins that must be connected the only circuit that is a 100% replacement for a switch is a relay contact. Assuming the switched current is very low a 4066-style CMOS switch (as Jim suggests) will also work.

Knowing a little about the circuit in the box will likely make the circuit much easier. Very likely either T1 or T2 is connected to either ground or 3V3.

Let's for instance assume that T1 is connected to ground, hence T2 must be pulled low to active the transmitter. In this case a simple diode from T2 to the arduino output will do. If T2 is connected to 3V3 (hence T1 must be pulled high to activate) (assuming you use a 5V arduino) a simple voltage divider between the arduino ouput and T1 will do (1k + 2k2).

The knowledge about T1 and T2's connections can be obtained by using a multimeter, or by inspecting the PCB inside the transmitter.

You circuit might work or not, depending on the polarity of the current that flows from T1 to T2. You circuit assumes that T1 is always more positive that T2, which (without further information) has a probability of 50%.

Comment: There are often questions here from people wanting to control motors with MCU logic signals.  Relays and motor control chips are often recommended. From an EE take: Would the 4066 chip be a viable option? The chip looks like it can handle 15v. Using the pinout in this data sheet- http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=snos366a - would there be a risk to an MCU with a 12v motor circuit using pins 1 and 2 and an MCU powered with 5v writing to pin 13 controlling that switch? That chip is 28 cents at Tayda and seems like an inexpensive option.

Comment: @mike: does that have anything to do with the original question? BTW, the answer is NO, a 4066-style switch is not designed to handle the current required by even a small motor. If you don't like relays and motor driver chips you could consider a MOSFET driver chip.

Comment: -  My question was only tangentially related- which is why I made it a comment.  I like relays and motor driver chips just fine.  As I noted, questions surrounding them seem to come up often and I was curious as to whether the 4066 would be a player in that regard.  I am unfamiliar with the chip.  You seem to feel it could not handle the required current.  That answers my curiosity.  Thank you.  Sorry that you took unneeded offense.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense to me at all. You want to operate a switch SW1 to turn a transistor ON and OFF so that it will connect two terminals T1 and T2.
If you already have to operate a physical switch why not just connect this across T1 and T2 and cut out the unnecessary transistor switch, saving you the cost of the transistor, three resistors and the time trying to get it to work. Or am I missing something?

[image]

With the new information (and yes I was missing it because it hadn't been given)

[image]

A transistor may be used as a switch but it is not a switch. The 4066 quad bi-lateral switch chip is designed to switch analogue signals controlled by a digital high/low input. If the switch resistance is too high you could always replace it with a relay switch.

For a better analogue switch you might want to use the DG723 from Vishay. 
http://ebookbrowse.com/dg723-pdf-d51984267
They come in at about £1.50 (UK)

[image]

Comment: The switch will eventually be replaced by an arduino controller, which doesn't have a "switch off" mode. Thus the use of the transistor.

Comment: @Antoine_935 Is there a specific pulse going from T1 to T2 or just an analog voltage? Why not just duplicate this pulse/voltage from the controller and skip the switch all together? By the say, I said "controller" and not "arduino controller" since that would be huge overkill unless this is part of a much more complicated system.

Comment: @Antoine_935 - I'm not psychic, I can only deal with the information given in a question. As your question was posed it did not make sense